# Python logic in assignment

Tags: python

Given that `secure` is a boolean, what do the following statements do?

Especially the first statement.

1. `protocol = secure and "https" or "http"`
2. `newurl = "%s://%s%s" % (protocol,get_host(request),request.get_full_path())`

Comment: I love this python assignment trick, really handy ! :-)

Comment: I try avoid this trick.  It's more confusing than handy.

Answer (score 13):

I hate this Python idiom, it's completely opaque until someone explains it.  In 2.6 or higher, you'd use:

```
protocol = "https" if secure else "http"
```

Comment: thanks! I "knew" what the results would be but the statement seemed cryptic to me and I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 5):

It sets `protocol` to "https" if `secure` is true, else it sets it to "http".

Try it in the interpreter:

```
>>> True and "https" or "http"
'https'
>>> False and "https" or "http"
'http'
```

Answer (score 5):

Python generalises boolean operations a bit, compared to other languages. Before the "if" conditional operator was added (similar to C's `?:` ternary operator), people sometimes wrote equivalent expressions using this idiom.

`and` is defined to return the first value if it's boolean-false, else returns the second value:

```
a and b == a if not bool(a) else b #except that a is evaluated only once
```

`or` returns its first value if it's boolean-true, else returns its second value:

```
a or b == a if bool(a) else b #except that a is evaluated only once
```

If you plug in `True` and `False` for `a` and `b` in the above expressions, you'll see that they work out as you would expect, but they work for other types, like integers, strings, etc. as well. Integers are treated as false if they're zero, containers (including strings) are false if they're empty, and so on.

So `protocol = secure and "https" or "http"` does this:

```
protocol = (secure if not secure else "https") or "http"
```

...which is

```
protocol = ((secure if not bool(secure) else "https") 
            if bool(secure if not bool(secure) else "https") else "http")
```

The expression `secure if not bool(secure) else "https"` gives "https" if secure is `True`, else returns the (false) `secure` value. So `secure if not bool(secure) else "https"` has the same truth-or-falseness as `secure` by itself, but replaces boolean-true `secure` values with "https". The outer `or` part of the expression does the opposite - it replaces boolean-false `secure` values with "http", and doesn't touch "https", because it's true.

This means that the overall expression does this:

- if `secure` is false, then the expression evaluates to "http"
- if `secure` is true, then the expression evaluates to "https"

...which is the result that other answers have indicated.

The second statement is just string formatting - it substitutes each of the tuple of strings into the main "format" string wherever `%s` appears.

Answer (score 1):

The first line was answered well by the Ned and unwind.

The 2nd statement is a string replacement. Each %s is a placeholder for a string value. So if the values are:

```
protocol = "http"
get_host(request) = "localhost"
request.get_full_path() = "/home"
```

the resulting string would be:

```
http://localhost/home
```

Answer (score 0):

In psuedocode:

```
protocol = (if secure then "https" else "http")
newurl = protocol + "://" + get_host(request) + request.get_full_path()
```

Comment: First line is no valid Python

Comment: It should be `"https" if secure else "http"`