# Python for loop with or?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, for-loop

Recently I came across some obfuscated python code, and I was having no problem separating out the pieces and understanding the little fragments of code. However, I came across one statement I didn't understand:

```py
v, x = 1500, 1000
C = range(v*x)
import struct
P = struct.pack
M, j = '<QIIHHHH', open('M.bmp','wb').write
for X in j('BM'+P(M,v*x*3+26,26,12,v,x,1,24)) or C:
```

In the last line of code, I don't understand how this `for` loop can work with an `or` sitting there. The code runs fine, but I have no idea what it's doing. I tried looking in the Python docs, but I didn't see anything. What does this code do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033298/python-logic-in-assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`write` always returns None, so this expression is just being used for the sideeffect of calling `j(...)`. The loop will always be over C

Partially deobfuscated version

```
import struct
v = 1500
x = 1000
C = range(v*x)
M = '<QIIHHHH'
with open('M.bmp','wb') as fin
    fin.write('BM'+struct.pack(M, v*x*3+26, 26, 12, v, x, 1, 24))
    for X in C:
        ...
```

The snippet appears to be writing the header of a bmp file. I guess the for loop would be writing the remainder

Answer (score 8):

If the return of j() == False, it iterates over C instead

Take a look at it in steps:

First, it evaluates this:

```
j('BM'+P(M,v*x*3+26,26,12,v,x,1,24))
```

Should that be considered equal to False (empty list, None, 0, etc), then it evaluates this:

```
C
```

and passes that as the iterable to the `for` loop

It should be noted that the `or` is not part of `for` syntax. It's evaluated prior to being passed into the `for` syntax you're familiar with